# X-Ray and In Front modes don't work together

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, object-mode

I ran into this problem while modeling a character: whenever I try to set an object to X-Ray mode, then when I change the viewport display setting for the object to "in front", my object sets itself to a weird wireframe. I didn't have this issue when I last opened this file, so I'm hoping it's a setting that I flipped by accident. What's going on here? See below for pictures:

1. Object displaying in solid mode with x-ray on
   [image]
2. Object displaying in solid mode with x-ray AND in front on
   [image]

Comment: Why not set the reference image in front and make it semi- transparent?

Comment: That works for the front view reference image, but I also have a side view reference image. There's something (bug and/or operator error) preventing me from also setting the side view to transparent. What's your preferred way to make images transparent?